@ConfigurationProperteis for Custom/Second Spring Boot AsyncTaskExecutor
I have a Spring Boot application where I currently use the autoconfigured AsyncTaskExecutor (which in my case will be an ThreadPoolTaskExecutor).
In case I later need an executor with a seperate/dedicated thread pool, in another place -- is there an equivalent configuration option as for when configuring a second/custom datasource which allows easy externalized tuning via @ConfigurationProperties?

it seems the underlying spring.task.execution ConfigurationProperties is a public class, so maybe it's possible to leverage that... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/dc78bd468c60fb79972dd4c425eddf25559dd92a/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/task/TaskExecutionProperties.java
